# On mobile view, for specific tab menu is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i use [this](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/the-big-picture/) bootstrap template for may web page. Everything works ok, only on page where i use table, on mobile view, menu is hidden but only on mobile view. On all other tabs menu is shown. Here is plunker

```
> https://plnkr.co/edit/aWOlh3mPqbW1TowAFdKK?p=preview
```

of my tab, where i have problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Ok, i include code, include problem.... what else need to do??? i dont get it

Comment: what have you tried ? and be more specific about your problem. don't use plnkr , use the snippet provided by SO

Comment: I use bootstrap templete, and make full web page. Everything working fine on mobile view. But only on one tab, where i use <table></table>, menu is hidden. In my question in plunker i provide full code, for ppl who want to help me, to show full structure of my code. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fix this. Problem was col-. I need to put class in table `class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"` and then order all th with class (in my case `<th class="text-center col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">`)